# Springboot interceptor exceludePathPatterns

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

I have a controller class shown below:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Resource
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/roleChange")
    public Map<String, Object> setUserRole(String uuid, String email, String roleId){
        return userService.setUserRole(uuid, email, roleId);
    }
}
```

And this is how I added the interceptor to registry:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/user/login","/user/role-control");
    }
}
```

It seems like this still intercepted a request to `/role-control`. Is there something I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Nothing wrong in excludePathPatterns. The method in Controller is for url `/roleChange` and excludedPath is `/user/role-control`. This is not a typo, right? and there is another method corresponding to `/role-control`

Comment: Yeah it's not. I figured it out /login is in a different path, it's not under /user lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: you can use `addPathPatterns()`